# prove that $ \int f = \lim \int f_n$ whenever $f_n \rightarrow f $ uniformly

Tags: measure-theory

I need help with the following exercise from Bartle's book

[image]

Specially with the equality. I know that is true if $f_n$ is a monotone increasing sequence of functions in $M^+$ but in this case that is not for sure.

Answer (score 2):

$|\int f_nd\mu-\int fd\mu|\leq \int |f_n-f| d\mu <\epsilon \mu(X)$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: could you explain the details... I don't  understand how to derive the equality...

Comment: The inequality $|\int f d\mu| \leq \int |f| d\mu$ is proved by splitting the integral into integrals over $\{f \geq 0\}$ and $\{f < 0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon>0$. By uniform convergence there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n \ge N$, then for all $x\in X$, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{\mu(X)+1}$, noting that $\mu(X)<\infty$ is essential here.

Thus, if $n\ge N$, we have $$\left|\int f \mathrm{d}\mu-\int f_n\mathrm{d}\mu\right|\le \int \left|f-f_n\right|\mathrm{d}\mu \le \sup_{x\in X}|f(x)-f_n(x)|\cdot \mu(X)<\frac{\epsilon}{\mu(X)+1}\cdot\mu(X)<\epsilon.$$ Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n\mathrm{d}\mu=\int f\mathrm{d}\mu$.